# Does PostgrSQL plpgsql allow declare procedure or function in Declare section like Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: postgresql, plsql, plpgsql

Can I declare a procedure or a function in another plpgsql block instead of creation beforehand?

For Example

```
DECLARE
    PROCEDURE some_procedure_name() AS $$
        ...
        BEGIN
        ...
        END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpsql

    ...

    BEGIN
        ...
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpsql
```

Comment: The docs will tell you, see [Declare](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html).

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that in PL/pgSQL.